# Comparing Carbon startOfDay() with now()->startOfDay() does not work properly

Tags: php, laravel, timestamp, laravel-5.8, php-carbon

I want to compare the Start Day of the **current date** with the Start Day of a **custom date**, retrieved from the DB (which is a UNIX timestamp).

So I coded this at the Controller:

```
foreach($popups as $popup)
{ 
    $date = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($popup->datep);

    if($date->startOfDay()->eq(now()->startOfDay())){
        $result = true;
    }
    if($result == true){
        // show some data
    }
}
```

So I tested this with three different dates. And `dd()` results of each one goes like this:

```
$date1 = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($popup[0]->datep);
dd($date1->startOfDay()); // returns date: 2021-11-08 00:00:00.0 Asia/Tehran (+03:30)

$date2 = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($popup[1]->datep);
dd($date2->startOfDay()); // returns date: 2021-11-09 00:00:00.0 Asia/Tehran (+03:30)

$date3 = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($popup[2]->datep);
dd($date3->startOfDay()); // returns date: 2021-11-10 00:00:00.0 Asia/Tehran (+03:30)
```

And the result of `dd(now()->startOfDay());` is `date: 2021-11-09 00:00:00.0 Asia/Tehran (+03:30)`. Which means only the `$popup[1]->datep` is capable of showing.

But now the problem is, it shows the 3rd date as well! However, the Start Day of it is equals to **10** while the current Start Day is **11**.

So what's going wrong here?

How can I properly compare the Start Day of the current date with the Start Day of retrieved data?

---

**Full Code:**

```
    $output = "";
    $result = false;
    $titleshow = "";
    $popups = PopUp::all();
    
    if($popups->count() > 0)
    { 
        foreach($popups as $popup)
        { 
            $date = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($popup->datep);

            if($date->startOfDay()->eq(now()->startOfDay())){
                $result = true;
            }
            
            if($result == true){
                if($popup->showtitle == 1){
                    $titleshow = $popup->title;
                }
                $links = explode(",",$popup->linkp);
                $paths = explode(",",$popup->image_path);
                $matns = explode(",",$popup->matn);
                for($i=0;$i<=count($links)-1;$i++){
                    if(!empty($links[$i])){
                        $output .='<a href=" '.$links[$i].' "><img src=" '. URL::to('popups/'.$paths[$i]).' " style="width: 100%;"></a></br><p>'.$matns[$i].'</p></br>';
                    }else{
                        break;
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
    json_encode($output);
```

Then at the Blade, I tried showing `$output` as Sweet Alert pop message.

Comment: For the record, Carbon has the  `$date->isToday()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to "reset" the status of `$result` at the beginning of each iteration:

```
foreach($popups as $popup)
{
    $result = false; 
    $date = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($popup->datep);

    if($date->startOfDay()->eq(now()->startOfDay())){
        $result = true;
    }
    if($result == true){
        // show some data
    }
}
```

Once `$popup[1]->datep` is hit `$result` is set to `true` no matter your condition - that's why `$popup[2]->datep` also shows up.

**Edit**:
I'd get rid of `$result` and do the "calculations" right in your date check:

```
<?php
$output = "";
$titleshow = "";
$popups = PopUp::all();

if($popups->count() > 0) { 
    foreach($popups as $popup) { 
        $date = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($popup->datep);
        if($date->startOfDay()->eq(now()->startOfDay())) {
            if($popup->showtitle == 1) {
                $titleshow = $popup->title;
            }
            $links = explode(",",$popup->linkp);
            $paths = explode(",",$popup->image_path);
            $matns = explode(",",$popup->matn);
            for($i=0; $i <= count($links)-1; $i++) {
                if(!empty($links[$i])) {
                    $output .='<a href=" '.$links[$i].' "><img src=" '. URL::to('popups/'.$paths[$i]).' " style="width: 100%;"></a></br><p>'.$matns[$i].'</p></br>';
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
echo json_encode($output);
```

Also note that you need to `echo` or `return` your `json_encode($output);`

Comment: You're right. But if I add the `$result = false;` in the foreach, it sets to `false` in the 3rd round. Then nothing shows up at the end.

Comment: Then most likely something in `// show some data` doesn't do what it should do. When `$popup[1]->datep`'s `$result` is true it should `// show some data`. (Btw, you could skip the `$result` setting/checking and show data right in your date comparison condition)

Comment: Can you checkout my **Full Code** please. I would really appreciate if you give me a suggestion about it.

Comment: Edited my answer, please see if that works. `json_encode($output)` will do nothing on its own, so I `echo`d it